# how do I allow cross origin resource sharing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I don't know why my ajax CORS doesn't work..

ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        $.ajax({
            url: "SERVER_URL_AND_PARAMETERS",
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            },
            dataType:"json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success:function(data, textStatus, xhr){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(xhr,status,error){
                alert("code:"+xhr.textStatus+"\n"+"message:"+error.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error.log); 

            }

        });

    });
```

response headers

```
 Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
    Cache-Control:no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Language:ko-KR
    Content-Length:0
    Content-Type:text/plain
    Date:Mon, 02 Nov 2015 07:19:54 GMT
    Expires:Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=100
    Set-Cookie:SOME_COOKIES; Expires=Tue, 01-Nov-16 07:19:53 GMT; Path=/
    X-UA-Compatible:IE=EmulateIE8, requiresActiveX=true
```

request headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:SERVER_URL
Origin:http://CLIENT_URL
Referer:http://CLIENT_URL/AND/JSP_FILE_PATH.jsp?lineCd=CODE1&prdtCode=CODE2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
```

chrome error detail

```
MLHttpRequest cannot load SERVER_URL_AND_PARAMETER Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'CLIENT_URL' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I don't know what is the problem on my code. I am working on CLIENT_URL side web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS headers such as `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` MUST be set by the server, not by the client.  It is the server that grants CORS access to clients, not the other way around.  You can't give yourself CORS access from the browser.

From the [MDN section on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), here's a descriptive quote:

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP
>   headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are
>   permitted to read that information using a web browser.  Additionally,
>   for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in
>   particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with
>   certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers
>   "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server
>   with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from
>   the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request
>   method.  Servers can also notify clients whether "credentials"
>   (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with
>   requests.

In particular, note the part that says "allow servers to describe the set of origins that are permitted to read that information using a web browser".